# mysql split data from one table into two tables with mapping(association) preserved

Tags: mysql, insert, associations, primary-key

Lets say I have a table called Students with columns Name, mobile, email, preferred course, preferred school, gender, age, address, qualification, designation, homephone, workphone

I want to select the data from the Students table and insert into 2 tables such as,
Inquiries => (with columns) Id, Name, Mobile, Email
Enrollments => (with columns) Id, inquiry_id, name, mobile, email, preferred course, preferred school, gender, age, address, qualification, designation, homephone, workphone

**How to populate the inquiry_id in the enrollments table with the correct id value from the inquiry table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the id of the last inserted inquiry;

```
INSERT INTO inquiries (name, mobile, ...

INSERT INTO enrollments (inquiry_id, name, ...) 
   VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'myname', ...
```

[A simple SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56746/2).

Another approach for bulk moving is to add a temporary column to hold the old id so that you can use the correct one for the second insert;

```
ALTER TABLE inquiries ADD COLUMN oldid INT;

INSERT INTO inquiries (..., oldid) SELECT ..., id FROM students;
INSERT INTO enrollments (inquiry_id, ...)
  SELECT (SELECT id FROM inquiries WHERE students.id=oldid), ...
  FROM students;

ALTER TABLE inquiries DROP COLUMN oldid;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39be7/1).

Comment: @beck03076 Added an SQLfiddle with an example.

Comment: No... listen.. I have 10000 rows in Students table, Im going to run INSERT INTO inquiries SELECT null,null,fname,lname,null,concat(email,", ",email2),null,phone,null,mobile,null,null,now(),null FROM Students; How to solve this?

Comment: I want the inquiry ids to be mapped from this inquiries table to enrollment table.

Comment: Should I write a stored procedure, create a cursor for the Students table and for each record insert into inquiry and then insert into enrollment with last_insert_id()..????

Comment: @beck03076 The simplest is probably to do a stored procedure that does it row by row, another possibility is to temporarily add a column 'oldid' to inquiries for mapping, and do something like `INSERT INTO inquiries SELECT null,null,fname,lname,null,concat(email,", ",email2),null,phone,null,mobile,null,null,now(),null,id FROM Students`, and `INSERT INTO enrollments (inquiry_id, name, ...) SELECT ((SELECT a.id FROM inquiries a WHERE a.oldid=students.id), 'myname', ...) FROM Students`, and then drop the temp column.

Comment: I love your second approach and Im going to do it.. I will tell once it works

Comment: @beck03076 Added another SQLfiddle.

Comment: @beck03076 You have extra parens `((SELECT ... now())` should just be `(SELECT ... NOW()`